# Optimize a sports site standings query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I've inherited an application that tracks game results for hockey leagues. The results table looks like the following:

```
[dbo].[league_division_games](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [division] [int] NULL,
    [team1] [int] NULL,
    [team1_score] [int] NULL,
    [team2] [int] NULL,
    [team2_score] [int] NULL,
    [shootout] [bit] NOT NULL)
```

The existing query is a nasty cursor that performs terribly. I won't even post it here!

I started rewriting this, but it's looking quite cludgy to me.

```
SELECT
    teams.id
    ,teams.name
    ,IsNull(COUNT(games.id), 0) AS GP
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN (teams.id = games.team1 AND games.team1_score > games.team2_score) OR (teams.id = games.team2 AND games.team2_score > games.team1_score) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS W
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN (teams.id = games.team1 AND games.team1_score < games.team2_score) OR (teams.id = games.team2 AND games.team2_score < games.team1_score) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS L
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN (teams.id = games.team1 AND games.team1_score = games.team2_score) OR (teams.id = games.team2 AND games.team1_score = games.team2_score) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS T
FROM
    dbo.league_division_teams teams
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.league_division_games games ON teams.id = games.team1 OR teams.id = games.team2
WHERE
    teams.division = @DIV
GROUP BY
    teams.id,
    teams.name
```

Basically I have to keep checking each side of the score for wins, losses, ties, goals against, goals for.

One bit of complexity - in hockey, if it's an overtime losses count as 1 point for the loser and 2 for the victor. Also, if it's a shootout then the goals for is equal to the lowest of the two scores.

For those reasons the aggregate case statements are going to get quite large, and probably won't perform well.

I've considered creating a CTE to flatten this out a bit, but haven't been down that road yet.

Has anyone approached this in a different way? I imagine these kinds of stats are pretty common.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach it is to just aggregate the 2 "sides" separately and combine them at the end. You'd have to play with it a bit to see if it performs better, but I'm thinking something like this:

```
select
    id, name, sum(gp), sum(w), sum(l), sum(t)
from (
    SELECT
        teams.id
        ,teams.name
        ,IsNull(COUNT(games.id), 0) AS GP
        ,CASE WHEN team1_score > team2_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS W
        ,CASE WHEN team1_score < team2_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS L
        ,CASE WHEN team1_score = team2_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS T
    FROM
        dbo.league_division_teams teams
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.league_division_games games ON teams.id = games.team1 

    union

    SELECT
        teams.id
        ,teams.name
        ,IsNull(COUNT(games.id), 0) AS GP
        ,CASE WHEN team2_score > team1_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS W
        ,CASE WHEN team2_score < team1_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS L
        ,CASE WHEN team2_score = team1_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS T
    FROM
        dbo.league_division_teams teams
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.league_division_games games ON teams.id = games.team2
)
group by
    id, name
```